# How can I use precision in Swift?

Tags: swift, double

```
heightInM = ((Double(heightInFeetText.text!)! * 30.48) + (Double(heightInInchText.text!)! * 2.54))/100

output =  Double(weightInKgText.text!)! / (heightInM * heightInM)
bmiOutput.text = String(output)
```

How can I format double value with 2 decimal points?

Comment: Beware of not force unwrapping everything with `!`, your app would crash if any of the values are nil. You'd better handle this with optional binding (`if let`).

Comment: I am beginner in iOS development. Thanks for your advice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `stringWithFormat` API, add specify how many digits would you like to see.

**Example:**

```
let floatValue = 2.333123211
let output = String(format: "%0.2f", floatValue) // prints 2.33
```

**In your case:**

```
bmiOutput.text = String(format: "%0.2f", output)
```